# How do I maintain aspect ratio with browser window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page built using HTML/CSS that is meant to be used for the sole purpose of being displayed on a TV. I've developed the page to fit perfectly within a 1920x1080 ratio, but I would like a way to have the page scale up or down with the exact same aspect ratio of the original design. Is there any Javascript script I could use to help maintain the constant ratio?

Edit: This will eventually be turned into a RoR application that will constantly update content such as news/events/etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a simple listen on window resize would solve the problem:

```
$(window).on('resize',funciton(){
  var self=$('#ur_id');
  self.height( self.width() * (1080/1920))
})
```

Comment: This would keep the aspect ratio of the container but not for the elements inside it though?

Comment: u would need to do it all in % not px ... But u should really consider redoing it in svg.

Comment: The content will be changing so just keeping everything as an image would defeat the purpose though?

Comment: SVG is not an image its much like HTML. u can use JS in it no problem. We use it at work for our call center's infoscreens

Comment: u can teach yourself SVG in a few hours, provided u know html/CSS already :)

Comment: So I should convert all of my fonts to an svg font? Or just my entire page?

Comment: That would be incredible. Thank you so much!

Comment: Wow, that's actually really awesome. Do you have an idea how it would work if I were to use actual .svg images as well? Also, how well does it work with photos?

Comment: U can mix and match u can even put html inside your svg.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS @media queries for this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
   /*Styles goes here*/
}
```

Or you can use `media = projection`

Comment: But I would like for it to scale under that as well. Would you suggest just creating multiple break points and adjusting the dimensions for each?

Comment: yes you can use specific media queries for specific resolutions, this will be clean approach

Comment: I've never even read anything about media = projection. Do you have a source for it? It sounds pretty handy!

Comment: @Spentacular you can google for it, here I found 1, http://www.codestyle.org/css/media/projection-BrowserSummary.shtml, or better http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html

Comment: I just didn't know if you had any other sources. Thanks for sending them!

Answer (score 0):

The design for a device supporting 1920x1080 resolution mostly is not applicable to a mobile device for example. Maybe you need to hide some elements (generally sidebar) or decrease the font-size, load a different logo... So the best solution is a [responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) using `@media` queries as @Mr. Alien suggest.

> Responsive web design is an approach to web design in which a site is crafted to provide an optimal viewing experience—easy reading and navigation with a minimum of resizing, panning, and scrolling—across a wide range of devices (from desktop computer monitors to mobile phones).

You can check some [Guidelines and Tutorials](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/) at SmashingMagazine.

Comment: I've tried implementing the design into a responsive one, but the biggest problem was the fonts not resizing properly (thank goodness for sass and the percentage function though).

Comment: With relative value (eg. em or %), the font size, line-height and margin spacing can be inherited ;)